# What exactly happened in the 2019 Nov Monero CLI hack?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, daemon

There were reports of Monero CLI binaries not matching for the v0.15 release in November of 2019. What exactly happened and how can it be prevented in the future? Did it only affect the cli wallet binaries? What about the monero v0.15 daemon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see:

https://web.getmonero.org/2019/11/19/warning-compromised-binaries.html

And:

https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/dyfozs/security_warning_cli_binaries_available_on/

> What exactly happened and how can it be prevented in the future?

Further information will become available once the full investigation is complete. Until then, there is no point in speculation.